# Cannot push to android emulator because of Read only file system

Tags: android, macos

I am trying to push a host file to my adb device.

So, I did:

```
[~/Library/Android/sdk/tools]$ emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_26_x86 -writable-system 
emulator: WARNING: System image is writable
emulator: ### WARNING: /etc/localtime does not point to /usr . 
/share/zoneinfo/, can't determine zoneinfo timezone name
emulator: ### WARNING: /etc/localtime does not point to 
/usr/share/zoneinfo/, can't determine zoneinfo timezone name
```

Now in a different console I do 
`adb push hosts /system/etc/hosts`

But I get the follwing  error:

> adb: error: failed to copy 'hosts' to '/system/etc/hosts': remote couldn't create file: Read-only file system
>   hosts: 0 files pushed. 0.1 MB/s (93 bytes in 0.001s)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
$emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_26_x86 -writable-system 
$adb root
$adb remount
$adb push hosts /system/etc/hosts
```

Comment: @CaoMindVu Nice! Worked for me. I was doing everything except for the `remount` step; as soon as I added that, walla!

Answer (score 19):

For those coming here in 2020:

In my case the steps in the answer didn't work as the version `30` API didn't support a writable system.

I had to use the version `28` API version.

Comment: Thank you! Kept me away from trying in the first place

Answer (score 1):

I found I needed the extra step of disabling verification. Have this working on emulators up to android 32 (current)

```
emulator -writable-system -- @emulator_name

adb root
adb shell avbctl disable-verification 
adb reboot
adb remount
adb push ./local.file /remote-location
```

Answer (score 0):

### Maybe its a missing directory!

Make sure you're pushing to a directory which exists. I made a mistake and added a `~` at the start when trying to push photos to the pictures folder on my emulator: it should be `adb push -s emulator-5554 harold /sdcard/Pictures`. I often navigate the system first, with `adb shell`

### For 2020,

**API level 30** has not changed anything, Ropstahs existing answer is just wrong, as I have always seen it work with API level 30 devices with & without Play Store (see the screenshot, named `Pixel_4_API_30`):

> Ropstah: the version 30 API didn't support a writable system.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: For me, Ropstahs' answer was correct. I tried with API 30 and 29 - got error "adb: error: failed to copy 'hosts' to '/system/etc/hosts': remote couldn't create file: Read-only file system". However, 28 worked with the same push command.